# How do i multiselect images in the Gallery and send there URL to my activity?

Tags: android

How do i multiselect images in the Gallery and send there URL to my activity?
In the gallery I have added my Item to the share menu. But i can only share
one image and making my Activity start. This code give me the URL for one image.
Is it possible to set up the Gallery or the share menu so that user can
select one or many pictures?

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) 
 { 
  if extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) 
  { 
    Uri uri = (Uri)extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); //path to image
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "path: "+     getRealPathFromURI(uri), 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show(); 
   return; 
} else if 
(extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) { 
    } 

} 
  public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) { String[] proj = { 
  MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }; Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, 
  proj, null, null, null); int column_index = 
  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
  cursor.moveToFirst(); return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got an answer to the question from group/android-developers.
Thanks Bruce!

What you want is ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.  You will receive a set of
Uris.

Something like:

```
  if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action))
  && Intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
  ArrayList<Parcelable> list =
 intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
 for (Parcelable p : list) {
   Uri uri = (Uri) p;
   /// do something with it.
 }
}
```

Just add android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE to your manifest.

Bruce

Comment: how can i use this code to my app .when i click on button than inbuilt gallery will be open and i m able to select multiple images from Gallery .  please suggest me

Comment: Can you mention the google group url to see the original answer?

Comment: this is the original answer plz checked https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Xfy5UdWqfks

Comment: i am getting error from your code,kindly can u explain it to me that waht is "action"?